# Broken Packages ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, grub2

I reinstalled ubuntu 16.04, and it ends up with error that it has some broken packages which were not installed.

After that, wifi, speakers and bluetooth is not working.

Kindly help me what to do!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point the best thing you can do is just reinstall it again. Or do you really want to have a system that has bugs from the beginning? Most probably it had some errors during installation. If it occurs again, I would check the hard drive. Maybe the HD is kaputt.

Comment: i did install again, but not fixed

Comment: Then try to download the image again and make new live disk as Tibor wrote in his post. If this doesn't work, you should check your hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

If the broken packages message popped up immediately after installation, it may be A) your disk is broken if you have installed it form DVD, or B) the downloaded image was broken. Download it again, and make a new live disk then reinstall it...

If that message popped up after updating your freshly installed system, I would recommend reinstalling, and disabling updates... (it happened to me that I installed ubuntu, installed proprietary nvidia driver, restarted and worked, and then I've done sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade, and when I restarted, the GUI broke...)